# Алгоритм поиска пользователей

Tags: алгоритм, поиск, структуры, структуры-данных, поисковые-системы

У меня есть данных с информацией о пользователях:

```
users: [{
  first_name: 'Вова',
  last_name: 'Нуйкин',
  domain: 'kebab'
}, {
  first_name: 'Вова',
  last_name: 'Воробьев',
  domain: 'vorobey'
}]
```

Моя задача, сделать поиск по пользователям, но я не знаю какой алгоритм поиска будет хорошим, для поиска пользователям, если я вбиваю в поисковой строке "Вова" или "Вова Ну" или "Нуйк" или "kebab".

Я написал функцию, в которой я проверяю первые `N` буквы в `user.first_name`, `user.last_name` и `user.domain`. Поиск работает, когда я печатаю "Вова", "Нуйкин", или "kebab", но начинаются проблемы, когда я ищу "Вова Нуйкин". В таком случае в `searchResults` записывается и "Вова Нуйкин" и "Вова Воробьев". Как я могу исправить это?

Это моя функция:

```
search = (users, value) ->
  searchResults = []
  for user in users
    for value in values
      if user.first_name.toLowerCase().slice(0, value.length).includes(value) or
      user.last_name.toLowerCase().slice(0, value.length).includes(value) or
      user.domain.toLowerCase().slice(0, value.length).includes(value)
        searchResults.push(user)
  return searchResults
```

Comment: Это плохой алгоритм. С ним будут проблемы не только из-за конкатенации имени и фамилии, но и из-за опечаток вроде *Шуйкин/Нуйкин* или *Воробьев/Варабьев*. Советую ознакомится с алгоритмами нечеткого поиска, основанными на измерении [расстояния Дамерау-Левенштайна](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau–Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: Моя задача не в проверке опечаток вроде Шуйкин/Нуйкин или Воробьев/Варабьев.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, такой алгоритм сработает:

1. Разделите ввод пользователя на слова по пробелам.
2. Для каждой записи таблицы включайте её в результат только если *каждое* слово ввода пользователя входит в *хотя бы одно* поле записи.

Если вам нужны неточные вхождения, попробуйте более сложную процедуру:

1. Разделите ввод пользователя на слова по пробелам.
2. Для каждой записи таблицы вычислите её эвристический коэффициент соответствия: чем больше она подходит, тем коэффициент больше. Например:

   - если слово из ввода совпадает с каким-то из полей таблицы, добавьте к индексу 1.1, и исключите это слово и это поле из дальнейшего сравнения для данной записи
   - если слово из ввода является подстрокой какого-то из полей таблицы, добавьте к индексу 1, исключите это слово из дальнейшего сравнения для данной записи, и понизьте вес данного поля
   - если слово из ввода является неточной подстрокой какого-то из полей таблицы, добавьте к индексу 1/(1 + к-во ошибок), исключите это слово из дальнейшего сравнения для данной записи, и понизьте вес данного поля
3. Отсортируйте записи таблицы по индексу соответствия, выводите верхний элемент, а также те, у которых значение индекса составляет не менее 80% от максимума.

(Цифры и коэффициенты взяты с потолка.)

Answer (score 1):

Для таких вещей пока ничего быстрей троичных деревьев не придумали. Ergo, если нужен точный поиск:

1. Сразу строим 2 дерева, в которых ключами будут либо имя, либо фамилия.
2. Разбиваем ввод на слова, и каждое слово ищем в обоих деревьях.
3. Результаты выводим только если есть совпадения и там, и там, если слов больше одного, или хотя бы в одном если слово одно.

При не очень большом количестве записей всё это может быть реализовано на клиентской стороне, и работать вообще без обращений к базе.Реализации троичных деревьев на JavaScript выгугливаются без проблем, например: [раз](https://github.com/jandre/js-ternary-tree), [два](https://github.com/ryankask/tritium) (обратите внимание на метод `prefixSearch()` в примерах - оно самое!) и т.д.